# C# trigger windows 10 media notification

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

How can I implement these Windows 10 "media notifications" into a C# WPF desktop application?

[image]

Comment: I have asked me the same. I have done so much research already on the internet and due to that i found completely nothing (i mean solutions that wouldnt take me weeks to do) i gave up on that. I am really curious if someone will have a solution.

Comment: @L.Guthardt true! There is a very detailed documentation on toast notifications by microsoft itself, but not a single word about these media notifications

Comment: Tbh i think you have to be a geek and need really deep knowledge about windows itself to be able to manipulate their volume slider.

Comment: But Spotify does it, too, and I don't think they would invest a huge amount of time and money implementing a feature only a few users will actually make use of. I know that Spotify is written in C++, but I thought as C# is kinda Microsofts flagship-language, there should be a way to use native Windows funtionality pretty easily

Comment: Yeah Spotify is the only application i know that does something like that. I mean there is any easy tutorial to do it for a UWP, but on the one hand i dont want a UWP and on the other hand i have no clue how to bind the notification to the windows volume slider.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon) on your own out yet? No matter what i try with it i cant get it working. [Thats](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf/) the NuGet package for it.

Comment: @L.Guthardt no, I didn't even know where to begin. What does that package do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149140/discussion-between-tom-doodler-and-l-guthardt).

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols?view=winrt-20348) class. Its usage it described on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls).

However, this API is designed for UWP so getting this to work in a regular desktop application like WPF takes a little more work. There are [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258150/systemmediatransportcontrols-not-found) here on StackOverflow that describe how to do this, but there is also some newer, official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) from Microsoft on how to use these WinRT APIs.

Unfortunately, the System Media Transport Controls API is not directly supported in Desktop apps [[5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api)], so it gets a little more complicated, as described here [[6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/winrt-com-interop-csharp)].

---

In short, for .NET 5:

1. Install the Windows 10 SDK of a version you like (e.g. through the VS Installer);
2. Change the target framework to the SDK version you installed, e.g. `net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0`.
3. Use the API interops as described on [[6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/winrt-com-interop-csharp)] to get an instance.

   In the case of SMTP, you'd want to use `Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControlsInterop`. This requires the handle to a window, which you can get with `WindowInteropHelper` in WPF.
4. Use the [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols?view=winrt-20348) instance as described on [[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls)].