# SystemMediaTransportControls not found

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I am writing a WPF application in C# using JetBrains Rider. Now I want to play MP3-files and also display these Windows 10 media controls next to the volume bar. I figured out I need to use SMTC, or SystemMediaTransportControls, to do that.

However, this class is in the namespace `Windows.Media`, so I added `using Windows.Media;` to my C# file, but this leads to `Cannot resolve symbol 'Windows'`. When I try to add a reference to `Windows.Media.dll` in the Rider 'Add reference'-dialog I can't find anything.

I tried directly editing the .csproj-file:

```
<Reference Include="Windows.Media">
  <HintPath>C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Media.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

which leads to the following error message:

```
Reference wasn't resolved by MsBuild:
Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. Could not load file or assembly 'Windows.Media.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

The only namespace I can find is `System.Windows.Media`, but this is a different one than `Windows.Media`.

So where can I find SMTC? And why can't I use `Windows.Media`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SystemMediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControls) is for UWP. But you can use UWP APIs in WPF project.

Follow the steps outlined in [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#loIRh3Tv4h5DRUpL.97).

Basically, reference these two files from `References->Add Reference->Browse...`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
```

Then add the namespace

```
using Windows.Media;
```

Comment: Nevermind, I needed to edit my csproj file manually because the Browse-dialog only shows `dll`s. I am now figuring out where to get the second file.

Comment: After I added both references, my XAML file is full of errors: Bindings are not working, properties are not recognized. But when I build and start the application, everything works fine. Is this a Rider problem?

Comment: @SapuSeven To find `Windows.winmd`, you need to choose `All Files (*)` when browsing otherwise it only shows `*.dll` files. I don't know what are the problems in XAML, but seems it can be fixed by a rebuild?

Comment: The file browser is from Rider, so I have no option to select file types. Anyway, I managed to import the file manually. Thanks for your suggestion to my second problem, but unfortunately a rebuild didn't help. I suspect this is a Rider problem, because the build output shows no errors or warnings.

Comment: I did some more digging and debugging and I found out that my program seems to use `IComponentConnector` from the newly added Windows reference instead of the desired `System.Xaml` reference for the XAML file. Maybe this can help, but I am stuck here...

Comment: Just come to realize `JetBrains Rider` is another IDE, I thought it was some library irrelevant for reproducing this issue. Sorry can't help you further on this since I don't use `JetBrains Rider`.

Comment: I finally ended up creating a separate project in the same solution with this references and referenced it from my main project.